# Ipod touch blink/flash white

Tags: ipod-touch

Hi my ipod touch (about 1.5 years old) recently started to blink/flash white when I use it. (Never completely white)
I tried restoring/updating the software, didn't work; tried pressing power+home button, also didn't work. Anything else I can try, or do I need to bring it in?

Answer (score 2):

inverter for lcd-display is likely going (which is part of the logic-board).  Or the backlight (part of the lcd-assembly).  Bring it in.